# Equal Comparisons Order of Sentence Troubles

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

I am currently learning comparisons in which each item being compared is equal. When using a sentence with tan/tanto/a/os/as, I am having trouble knowing the correct order of each sentence:

A text book section asks a question and wants the answer to be no.

> ?Tiene la Plaza San Martín más estatuas que la Plaza San Bolívar?

Would the correct answer be:

> No, la Plaza San Martín tiene tantas estatuas como la Plaza San Bolívar.

or

> No, tiene tantas estatuas la Plaza San Martín como la Plaza San Bolívar

Another Question:

> Hay más tiendas en la calle Luna que en la calle Londres?

Would the correct answer be:

> No, hay tantas tiendas en la calle Luna como en la calle Londres.

I am trying to learn the sentence structure of these sentences and why it would be that way.

Comment: All your answers are correct. The first answer is more commonly used than the second (at least in Colombia) but both are correct. The third has the same structure as the second and it's also ok.

Comment: Avoid some wording by saying: *no, una tiene tantas estatuas como la otra* and the same for *no, hay tantas tiendas en una como en la otra.*

Comment: A detail: Bolivar was a hero, not a saint. Is better _Plaza Simón Bolívar_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gramaticalmente son todas las respuestas validas pero te recomendaría que te quedes con: (suenan mejor para alguien de habla hispana)

> No, la Plaza San Martín tiene tantas estatuas como la Plaza San Bolívar.

y

> No, en la calle Luna hay tantas tiendas como en la calle Londres.